# how to create incremental numbers as attribute value using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I want to create an attribute called ID and want to assign the count value to that

input:

```
<section>
                <p>In reading and rounding negative numbers, the same rules apply. The negative number is preceded by a, –, or enclosed in parentheses. In business reports negative five may be written as <span class="inlineequation">
                        <m:math display="inline" alttext="" altimg="../images/ch01math3.png" altimg-width="17" altimg-height="12">
                            <m:mrow>
                                <m:mo>-</m:mo>
                                <m:mn>5</m:mn>
                            </m:mrow>
                        </m:math>
                    </span> or (5).</p>
                <div class="informalequation" id="P70010133850000000000000000114E1">
                    <m:math display="block" alttext="" altimg="../images/ch01math4.png" altimg-width="288" altimg-height="70">
                        <m:mrow>
                            <m:mtable columnalign="left">
                                <m:mtr columnalign="left">
                                    <m:mtd columnalign="left">
                                        <m:mrow>
                                            <m:mn>6</m:mn>
                                            <m:mo>+</m:mo>
                                            <m:mn>7</m:mn>
                                        </m:mrow>
                                    </m:mtd>
                                    <m:mtd columnalign="left">
                                        <m:mo>=</m:mo>
                                    </m:mtd>
                                    <m:mtd columnalign="left">
                                        <m:mrow>
                                            <m:mn>13</m:mn>
                                        </m:mrow>
                                    </m:mtd>
                                </m:mtr>
                                <m:mtr columnalign="left">
                                    <m:mtd columnalign="left">
                                        <m:mrow>
                                            <m:mtext>addends</m:mtext>
                                        </m:mrow>
                                    </m:mtd>
                                    <m:mtd columnalign="left">
                                        <m:mrow/>
                                    </m:mtd>
                                    <m:mtd columnalign="left">
                                        <m:mrow>
                                            <m:mtext>sum</m:mtext>
                                            <m:mo> </m:mo>
                                            <m:mtext>or</m:mtext>
                                            <m:mo> </m:mo>
                                            <m:mtext>total</m:mtext>
                                        </m:mrow>
                                    </m:mtd>
                                </m:mtr>
                            </m:mtable>
                        </m:mrow>
                    </m:math>
                </div>
            </section>
```

the above one is the input

Desired output:

```
<section>
                <p>In reading and rounding negative numbers, the same rules apply. The negative number is preceded by a, –, or enclosed in parentheses. In business reports negative five may be written as <span class="inlineequation">
                        <m:math id="0001" display="inline" alttext="" altimg="../images/ch01math3.png" altimg-width="17" altimg-height="12">
                            <m:mrow>
                                <m:mo>-</m:mo>
                                <m:mn>5</m:mn>
                            </m:mrow>
                        </m:math>
                    </span> or (5).</p>
                <div class="informalequation" id="P70010133850000000000000000114E1">
                    <m:math id="0002" display="block" alttext="" altimg="../images/ch01math4.png" altimg-width="288" altimg-height="70">
                        <m:mrow>
                            <m:mtable columnalign="left">
                                <m:mtr columnalign="left">
                                    <m:mtd columnalign="left">
                                        <m:mrow>
                                            <m:mn>6</m:mn>
                                            <m:mo>+</m:mo>
                                            <m:mn>7</m:mn>
                                        </m:mrow>
                                    </m:mtd>
                                    <m:mtd columnalign="left">
                                        <m:mo>=</m:mo>
                                    </m:mtd>
                                    <m:mtd columnalign="left">
                                        <m:mrow>
                                            <m:mn>13</m:mn>
                                        </m:mrow>
                                    </m:mtd>
                                </m:mtr>
                                <m:mtr columnalign="left">
                                    <m:mtd columnalign="left">
                                        <m:mrow>
                                            <m:mtext>addends</m:mtext>
                                        </m:mrow>
                                    </m:mtd>
                                    <m:mtd columnalign="left">
                                        <m:mrow/>
                                    </m:mtd>
                                    <m:mtd columnalign="left">
                                        <m:mrow>
                                            <m:mtext>sum</m:mtext>
                                            <m:mo> </m:mo>
                                            <m:mtext>or</m:mtext>
                                            <m:mo> </m:mo>
                                            <m:mtext>total</m:mtext>
                                        </m:mrow>
                                    </m:mtd>
                                </m:mtr>
                            </m:mtable>
                        </m:mrow>
                    </m:math>
                </div>
            </section>
```

as your can see that the above example there is an "id" attribute in `m:math` tag, the `m:math` tag can come on any place in the file

So anybody suggest an xslt way to do that

Thanks

Comment: Look at `xsl:number`. P.S. Please select either XSLT 1.0 or 2.0, not both.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, would you share some example, sorry I am new to XSLT

Comment: No. Do a search, you will find many examples. Then, if you run into a **specific** problem, post your code.

Comment: sorry for that, but Thank you so much for your support, I have found a solution as you said in, and it work like charm

<xsl:number count="m:math" format="1" level="any"/>